# Multiple mod_rewrite Rules in .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following in my .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /rewrite/index.php?pages=$1 [L]
```

Which works great to rewrite all the files and directories that do not exist.
But now I need to do another more specific rewrite

The condition should be "If the requested URI does not exist AND it ends with attendees/" then Apply RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /rewrite/attendees.php?pages=$1 [L]

How could this be applied?

At first I thought it would be read in order of listing and thus tried:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} employee   [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /rewrite/attendees.php?pages=$1 [L] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /rewrite/index.php?pages=$1 [L]
```

But failed...

---

SOLVED USING THIS:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (employee) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /rewrite/employee.php?pages=$1 [L]   

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /rewrite/index.php?pages=$1 [L]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [multiple mod\_rewrite rules in .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10089097/multiple-mod-rewrite-rules-in-htaccess)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add another `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} attendees/$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /rewrite/index.php?pages=$1 [L]
```